# Inequality in four real variables

Tags: inequalities

How can we prove that the following inequality in four real variables?
$$3dc^2+3bc^2+3d^2c-6dc+3b^2c-4abc-6bc+3ad^2-4abd+3a^2d-6ad+ab^2+a^2b-2ab\ge 0~,$$
with $a,b,c,d\ge 2$.

Comment: Could you please suggest me a helpful software tool to verify that this inequality is true? WolframAlpha is not helpful in this case.

Comment: Why do you believe it to be true?

Comment: Yes, I run several computation experiments and there are some other reason to believe that is true, related to the original problem where this inequality has been originated.

Comment: i think this can be proven using am-gm and the fact that all the variables are greater than 2

Comment: I could simply work under the $4!=24$ assumptions corresponding to all possible ordering of the four variables, e.g., $a\ge b\ge c\ge d$, etc., but it would not be elegant at all, and it would seem a very (long) "amateur" approach.

Comment: Hopefully there exists a very elegant approach to solve it quickly...

Comment: Do you know when does equality occur? Did you try the substitutions $a=2+x$ etc?

Comment: Thank you Fedor. Equality cannot occur with the constraints that all four variables are at least $2$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The inequality is false for $a=1799, b=105, c=1024, d=4$.

---

This counterexample was found and verified with Mathematica, as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Iosif. How did you find these values?

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati : I have added the way the counterexample was found.

Comment: thank you very much.